# how can i order by date in descending order or ascending order in sql query using visual studio

Tags: sql, vb.net

My database table (date_of_call) contains:

```
4/02/2017
4/21/2017
4/01/2017
4/09/2017
```

And i want my query to return:

```
4/21/2017
4/09/2017
4/02/2017
4/01/2017
```

Here is the code:

```
        'viewing data
        If Not con.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
            'open connection

            con.Open()

        End If

        Dim da As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("select * DATE(updated_at) AS updated_date from approvedmasterlist where remarks in ('Approved') and ORDER BY DATE(updated_at) DESC ", con)

        Dim dt As New DataTable
        'fill data to datatable
        da.Fill(dt)

        'offer data in data table into datagridview
        DataGridView1.DataSource = (dt)

        'close connection
        con.Close()
```

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> ORDER BY DATE(updated_at) DESC
> ```

You've asked for the data to be ordered by `updated_at` so it is. Change this to update the order.